# Login fails in first attempt each time in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have wordpress ecommerce website. When i am trying to login to any account first time whether it is customer account or admin account it shown invalid address: your email address. But when i try to login with same credentials for second time it is logged in successfully. So basically it fails for the first time everytime but gets success in the second time. How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

-Clear Cookies to Resolve Login Issues

WordPress uses cookies for login authentication, so the first step in troubleshooting WordPress login issues is the simplest one. Clear your browser cookies and cache. Also make sure that your browser has cookies enabled. After doing that restart your browser and then try to login. This should fix the issue for most folks.
Clearing cookies and cache in Google Chrome

-Deactivate All Plugins

Sometimes WordPress plugins can cause this issue specially if there is a conflict between two plugins. To deactivate all your WordPress plugins, connect to your web hosting using an FTP client. Rename /wp-content/plugins/ directory to plugins_backup. This will deactivate all WordPress plugins installed on your website. We also have a detailed tutorial on how to deactivate all WordPress plugins when unable to access WP-Admin. Once you have deactivated all plugins, try to logging in to your WordPress site. If you succeed, then this means that one of your plugins was causing the issue.

-Delete .htaccess File

Sometimes .htaccess file can get corrupted which can result in internal server errors or login page refreshing error. Simply access your website through FTP. Backup the .htaccess file in your computer and then delete it from your website’s root directory. You may want to delete .htaccess file in wp-admin directory as well if it exist. Try logging in again. If you succeed, then this means that your .htaccess file were stopping you from logging into WordPress. Once you are logged in, simply go to Settings » Permalinks and click Save. This will generate a new .htaccess file.

Not a 100% sure youre issue is listed but have you tried this ?

REF: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/

Comment: You should quote the relevant text from that link in case the link were to go offline, we'd lose the context and your answer wouldn't be valid anymore. Keep it as a reference obviously in your answer, obviously